# Path.GetDirectoryName in C# .net core

Tags: c#, linux, path, nunit, .net-core-2.0

I am having a test case in .Net Core 2 where I am providing below input to `Path.GetDirectoryName`.

> @"C:" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar

When I assert for `Path.GetDirectoryName`in my test case, it returns `null`for Windows OS but returns `C:`for Linux OS, why so?
Can anyone please explain what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, `C:\` is a root directory. It doesn't have a name.

On Linux, `C:\` is also a directory. It's name is `c:` and - since you used a relative path - it's a sub-directory of the current directory.

The problem is that you have correctly used `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` so that the provided path works in both operating systems, but you have used a drive designator (C:), which is something that doesn't exist in Linux.

Comment: Gotcha, I have modified my test cases accordingly.